# How to keep Activity running even if it's in background

Tags: android, react-native, background-process

I'm creating an app using react-native to play audios from iframes using a library. But, the problem here is, if the user minimize the app, it just stops playing. What I want to do is simply continue to execute the activity even if the user changes it.

Comment: you can use services which runs in background

Comment: This is where you should start https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services